# What's the equivalent of reader = csv.reader(...) for xlsx sheets?

Tags: python, csv, xlsx, file-read, reader

I have a script with

```
path=r"mypath\myfile.xlsx"

with open(path) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
```

but it won't work because the code is trying to open an xlsx file with a module made for csv files.

So, does an expression equivalent for xlsx files exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of the highlighted code for xlsx sheets is:

```
path=r"mypath\myfile.xlsx"

import pandas as pd

with open(path) as f:
        reader = pd.read_excel(f)
```